# Problems with css menu styles

Tags: css, vue.js

I am really new to working on this, the problem I have is two

What I am trying to do is give it to show the menu as shown in the following image:

[image]

I can not put the option that was selected underlined, and so that the displayed menu is horizontal, what I have is this:

[image]

Searching the web I have not found anything to solve it or something to take an example to solve my problem, I am working with CSS and Vue.Js, if someone can tell me how to solve this

Underline the selected menu and see the menu displayed horizontally

My Code:

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion-mbl-menu">
      <div class="panel">
        <b-navbar-toggle target="collapse-cat-lvl1-469">
          Accesorios
          <img src="@/assets/images/layout/menu/chevron.svg" class="icon">
        </b-navbar-toggle>
        <div style="background-color:white;">
          <b-collapse id="collapse-cat-lvl1-469">
            <div data-cat-acc="473" class="grid-item parent-lvl-2">
              <a class="link -1 grid-sty-1" href="#" target="_self" data-menu-item-id="473">
                <span class="text">GTI</span>
              </a>
            </div>
            ...
            (other menu options)
            ...
          </b-collapse>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="panel">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggler collapsed"> ¿Necesitas ayuda? </button>
      </div>
    </div>
```

My code CSS

```
    @media (max-width: 828px) {
      #menu-header.show {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
        -ms-transform: translateX(0);
        transform: translateX(0);
      }
      #menu-header {
        display: block ;
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 1;
        background-color: #FFF;
        left: 0;
        top: 100px;
        height: -webkit-calc(100% - 50px);
        height: -moz-calc(100% - 50px);
        height: calc(100% - 50px);
        width: 90%;
        padding: 20px 20px;
        max-width: 87.5%;
        transform: translateX(-100%);
        transition: transform 650ms ease;

        .grid-sty-1 {
            height: 55px;
            display: -webkit-box;
            display: -ms-flexbox;
            display: -webkit-flex;
            display: -moz-box;
            display: flex;
            -webkit-box-align: center;
            -ms-flex-align: center;
            -webkit-align-items: center;
            -moz-box-align: center;
            align-items: center;
            height: 40px;
            font-size: 16px;
            font-family: "VWHead-Bold", sans-serif;
            position: relative;

            a{
                text-decoration: none;
                outline: none !important;
                padding-right: 15px;
                position: relative;
                display: -webkit-box;
                display: -webkit-flex;
                display: -moz-box;
                display: -ms-flexbox;
                display: flex;
                -webkit-box-align: center;
                -webkit-align-items: center;
                -moz-box-align: center;
                -ms-flex-align: center;
                align-items: center;
            }

            > .text {
                padding-left: 15px;
                color: #001E50;
            }
        }

        .navbar-greetings{
          font-family: 'VWHead-Regular';
          font-size: 24px;
          line-height: 29px;
          display: flex;
          align-items: center;
          color: #001E50;
        }


        #accordion-mbl-menu {
          margin: 0;

          .panel {
            box-shadow: none !important;
            background-color: transparent;
            border-radius: 0;
            border: 0;
            margin-bottom: 0;

            > button.collapsed {
              color: #001e50;

              > .icon{
                -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
                transform: rotate(0deg);
              }
            }

            > button.not-collapsed > .icon {
                -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
                transform: rotate(180deg);
            }

            > button {
              margin: 0px;
              padding: 0px;
              width: 100%;
              height: 55px;
              font-size: 20px;
              font-family: "VWHead-Bold";
              font-weight: normal;
              color: #2f3538;
              text-decoration: none;
              outline: none !important;
              border-bottom: 1px solid #dee1e3;
              padding-right: 15px;
              position: relative;
              display: -webkit-box;
              display: -webkit-flex;
              display: -moz-box;
              display: -ms-flexbox;
              display: flex;
              -webkit-box-align: center;
              -webkit-align-items: center;
              -moz-box-align: center;
              -ms-flex-align: center;
              align-items: center;

              > .icon {
                width: 20px;
                height: 20px;
                fill: currentColor;
                -webkit-transition: all 350ms ease;
                transition: all 350ms ease;
                position: absolute;
                right: 15px;
                top: auto;
              }

              .collapse.in {
                display: block;
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Any way to style this?

Answer (score 2):

#### To show underline on hover

```css
.class:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

#### To display horizontal

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
```